# Best Way To Design Database to Accommodate Indeterminate Number of Fields Per User?

Tags: sql, database-design, data-structures

I'm trying to understand how to design a database that can accommodate an indeterminate number of fields per User.

For example, User1 is involved in Projects A, B and C.  User2 is involved in Projects A, C, E and G while User3 is involved in Projects A, B, C, D, E, F and G.

A table with Users listed in rows and then 7 more columns to record the Projects they're involved in would serve quite nicely... until I have to accommodate User4 who winds up being involved in 100 projects, which, in my model, would require 100 columns for keeping track.

There would ultimately be no way of knowing in advance how many columns to define.

I could flip it around and associate User1 & User3 with Project B, but then further on down the road, after there are 10,000 Projects, I'd have to look through each Project record to produce a complete list of Projects that a given User has been involved in, which seems terribly inefficient.

So... how to keep track?  Just can't quite wrap my head around this one.

Am total newbie, so forgive me if this is poorly stated or grossly elementary.

Thanks,

Ben

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you may be trying to mix these two entities (`user` and `project`) into a single table, which really isn't the best way to go.

A different approach is to have your user info in a `user` table, project info in a `project` table, and another "link" table like `user_projects`, which would just contain the ID fields from the `user` and `project` tables, one entry for each user in each project.

an example schema:

```
user (userID, firstName, lastName)

project (projectID, projectTitle)

user_projects (userID, projectID)
```

To select project titles for user 3, you could do something like:

```
SELECT p.projectTitle 
FROM project p INNER JOIN user_projects up ON p.projectID = up.projectID
WHERE up.userID = 3
```

The point of the `user_projects` table is to link the information contained in the `user` and `project` tables, that is all.

Comment: Ah yes. Projects are limited to 20 contributors as it is, so ProjID's as rows then 20 columns for (potential) contributor UserID's. Does that mean I'm resigned to SELECT ProjID WHERE column_1=UserID OR column_2=UserID OR... column_20=UserID?  Or can I do that part more efficiently?

Comment: Thanks a TON for your efforts here, kaveman.  I'm going to have to try it before I'll get it completely, but let me re-state my understanding & if you read this you tell me if I get it: when a User contributes to a Project, a new row containing ProjID & UserID is added to the user_projects table. Then I can easily get ProjID's wherever the ID of the User in question is also present.  That seemed easy enough to say. Make sense?  Thanks again...

Comment: @Benjamin - you are welcome. It sounds like you have the right idea now. Consider marking one of the answers as "accepted" if it helped you...this will help others who may have similar questions and also improve the likelihood that future questions you ask will receive attention

Answer (score 3):

Typical many-to-many relation.

You need to crate a table, where each entry would be a relation: `user_id`, `project_id`.
If some user (id=`uid`) is involved with project (id=`pid`), then and only then there's a pair (record with 2 columns) in that table: `user_id`, `project_id`.

Yes, this may sound strange to person never seen this, but this is how it's made everywhere and DBs are ok with processing speed of such tables.

If later you decided, every user should have some role in project, you'll be able to add other fields to that table.

Comment: That helps. I didn't realize the "many-to-many" term was what I was looking for. A quick Google search indicates that might be exactly the cat I'm trying to skin. Thanks.